# How to avoid Multiple clicks on the menu item efficiently using kotlin in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

> Im using one menu button in toolbar but i want to avoid multiple clicks.

Comment: There is no direct way.. You can throttle the process with a Flag.. Something [Like This](https://medium.com/@simonkarmy2004/solving-android-multiple-clicks-problem-kotlin-b99c06135da0).

Comment: Disable the button after it's clicked?

Comment: Throttling it is the best way I've found. Disabling it doesn't work for fast double-taps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class SafeMenuClickListener(
    private var defaultInterval: Int = 1000,
    private val onSafeClick: (MenuItem?) -> Unit
): Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener {
  private var lastTimeClicked: Long = 0
  override fun onMenuItemClick(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    var recentClickTime: Long = lastTimeClicked
    lastTimeClicked = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - recentClickTime < defaultInterval){
      return false
    } else{
      onSafeClick(item)
      return true
    }
  }
}



    //In another kotlin file create a function 
fun Toolbar.setSafeMenuClickListener(onSafeClick: (MenuItem?) -> Unit) {
    val safeMenuClickListener = SafeMenuClickListener(defaultInterval = 1000,onSafeClick = ({
        onSafeClick(it)
    }))
    setOnMenuItemClickListener(safeMenuClickListener)
}



 // SetOnMenuClickListner instead of setOnMenuItemClickListner
    toolbar.setOnMenuClickListner{
        doSomething()
    }
```